# How am I able to change the CSS Module output depending on development or production mode?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I finally figured out how to use `localIdentName` with Vue's Nuxt.js

In my Nuxt.config.js

```js
loaders: {
   cssModules: {
     modules: {
       localIdentName: "[local]--[hash:base64:6]",
     }
   }
}
```

This works great with my components scss

```html
<style module lang="scss">
    .example{
        color:black;
    }
</style>
```

Then, in that module

```html
<div :class="$style.example"></div>
```

Outputs:

```html
<div class="example--ofjsig"></div>
```

Hooray!

But how can I have it so that it only does this in development, and in production it omits the `[local]--` prefix? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `nuxt.config.js`, you could use a ternary based on `process.env.NODE_ENV` (which is set to `"production"` in production mode) to conditionally insert this prefix:

```js
loaders: {
   cssModules: {
     modules: {
       localIdentName: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
           ? "[hash:base64:6]"
           : "[local]--[hash:base64:6]"
     }
   }
}
```